# Rails - mark invalid nested fields

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Rails is not marking nested attributes as invalid when validations fail.

For example:
I have two models; `User` and `UserProfile`.

User contains `email` and `password`
UserProfile contains `username`, `first_name`, `last_name`, etc

`User` validates that `email` is present and unique
`UserProfile` validates that `username` is present and matches a regex

On the sign-up form, `User` accepts nested attributes for `UserProfile.username`.

If you leave all fields blank and press submit, all validation errors are showing correctly. However, only the fields that are directly related to `User` have the `.is-invalid` class, and the `username` field does not.

How do I get nested form fields to append the `.is-invalid` class on failed validations? Is that something I need to do manually somewhere?

`User` model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable,
         :confirmable, :lockable, stretches: 13

  # -- Relationships --------------------------------------------------------

  has_one :user_profile, dependent: :destroy
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :user_profile

  # -- Validations --------------------------------------------------------

  validates_presence_of :email
  validates_presence_of :password
  validates_presence_of :password_confirmation
end
```

`UserProfile` model:

```
class UserProfile < ApplicationRecord
  # -- Relationships --------------------------------------------------------

  belongs_to :user

  # -- Validations --------------------------------------------------------
  validates_presence_of :username
end
```

Sign up form:

```
= simple_form_for @user do |f|
  = render 'devise/shared/error_messages', resource: resource
  = f.simple_fields_for :user_profile, :user_profile do |up|
    = up.input :username, autocomplete: 'username'
  = f.input :email, autocomplete: 'email'
  = f.input :password, autocomplete: 'new-password'
  = f.input :password_confirmation, autocomplete: 'new-password'
  .mt-4.mb-0.col-12
    = f.submit t('submit'), class: 'btn btn-primary btn-block'
```

Note that in the view I'm using `simple_form`, but I tested the same with the out-of-the-box functionality.

Registrations controller:

```
class Users::RegistrationsController < Devise::RegistrationsController
  layout 'unauthenticated_blank', only: [:new, :create]
  before_action :configure_sign_up_params
  before_action :build_user

  protected

  def configure_sign_up_params
    devise_parameter_sanitizer.permit(:sign_up, keys: [:email, :password, :password_confirmation, user_profile_attributes: [:username]])
  end

  private

  def build_user
    @user = User.new
    @user.build_user_profile
  end
end
```

Comment: Can you post some code? It might help determine what is going on

Comment: Sure thing, I added some code now

Comment: I think the controller code might be more germane in this case

Comment: Sure, I added the controller code now